# Predefined parameters for Sonata list search

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I need to set several predefined options for showing list of entities.

Sonata code:

```
class SubscriptionAdmin extends Admin {
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('created_at')
            ->add('status', 'doctrine_orm_choice', [], 'choice', ['choices' = ['active'=>'ecmo.enum.user.active', 'inactive'=>'ecmo.enum.user.active']
        ;
}
```

How i can set, that, by default, sonata show only active users, sorted by `created_at` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this, setting the default values for the $datagridValues variable as below

```
class SubscriptionAdmin extends Admin
{   

   /**
    * Default Datagrid values
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $datagridValues = array (
           'status' => array ('type' => 1, 'value' => 1), // field status with value 1
           '_page' => 1, // Display the first page (default = 1)
           '_sort_order' => 'ASC', // Descendant ordering (default = 'ASC')
           '_sort_by' => 'name' // name of the ordered field (default = the model id field, if any)
      // the '_sort_by' key can be of the form 'mySubModel.mySubSubModel.myField'.
   );
}
```

Where 'status' should be substituted by the field that you want and you should specify the desired value, and 'type' value corresponds with the following:

```
1: =
2: >=
3: >
4: <=
5: <
```

That's to filter an integer field. In my case, I've used this without specifying type, and the value 1 is set as default.

Comment: you need add `type` to search parameter:

    'status' => [
        'type'  => 3, //no idea what is it 
        'value' => SubscriptionStatusEnum::ACTIVE, //value i need
    ],

Comment: Airam, stange, but for working only `type=>3`. `1` not working. Any idea what is it?

Comment: @bm13kk I have no idea. I've been looking for information in the Sonata documentation, but there is nothing. I remember this because in an older version of the documentation I read it, but the link is no longer accessible.